# NodeJS avconv output to stream

Tags: node.js, stream, avconv

I am using the avconv module for nodeJS

I am trying to send an input stream to avconv and have it output to a file stream

I keep getting this error:

> Error: read ECONNRESET at exports._errnoException (util.js:1008:11) at
>   Pipe.onread (net.js:563:26) code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET',
>   syscall: 'read' }

Here is my code:

```
const params = [
        '-i', 'pipe:0',
        '-c:v' , 'libx264',
        '-preset', 'medium',
        '-tune', 'film',
        '-profile:v', 'baseline',
        '-level', '30',
        '-c:a', 'copy',
        'pipe:1'
];

let stream = avconv(params);

fs.createReadStream('sample.mp4').pipe(stream);

stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('newFile.mp4'));
```

If I replace the `'pipe:1'` option with `'newfile.mp4'` and remove the line `stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('newFile.mp4'));` then `newFile.mp4` is created properly

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What node version are you using? Also, where is `avconv()` defined?

Comment: I am using node v6.3.0 and avconv is defined at the beginning of my js file with the rest of the requires:  `const avconv = require('avconv');`